# iOS 8 Game Center Error

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios8, xcode6

I updated my XCode and iOS. My codes worked well before update. Now I can't login game center. Console gives this error

```
GameKitHelper ERROR: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Center.";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. Sandbox is not enable in iOS 8. Need to enable Sandbox in Settings -> Game Center -> Sandbox.