# don't know what I have to do to add Game Center leaderboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I tried to add a Game Center leaderboard, first setting it on iTunes Connect but when I have to write the code in Xcode I don't know what I have to do. I want to open the leaderboard with a shake gesture and for that I will use this code in the ViewController.m file:

```
-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
       // Code you want to run when the shake began
       }
}
```

Is that code right?
And please can anyone help me what  I have to do for appear the leaderboard when shaking?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable GameCenter in the Project's capabilities tab
2. Create a `GKGameCenterViewController` instance
3. Set the appropriate `viewState` property
4. If necessary, set the `gameCenterDelegate` property
5. Present the VC:

   ```
   GKGameCenterViewController *vc = [GKGameCenterViewController new];
   vc.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
   vc.gameCenterDelegate = self;
   [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES];
   ```

Comment: I used this code but the message Game Center unavailable the player is not signed in appears and after that I can't interact with the screen(buttons, gestures, etc) :/

Comment: check your sandbox settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945420/ios-8-game-center-error/25945487#25945487

Comment: You'll also have to authenticate the local player using `[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] setAuthenticateHandler:]`